# Jqgrid Navgrid doesn't work

Tags: jqgrid

Im trying to add navgrid to a working jqgrid but it doesn't show. The documentation could be better imo.

```
$("#" + id + "Table").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: data,
        colNames: colNames,
        colModel: colModel,
        pager: '#' + id + 'Table',
        autowidth: true,
        scroll: false,
        forceFit: true,
        shrinkToFit: true,  //Width of columns should be expressed in integers which add to 100
        rowNum: <xsl:value-of select="$totalLength"/>,
        rowTotal: <xsl:value-of select="$totalLength"/>,
        sortname: defaultSortColumn,
        sortorder: defaultSortOrder,
        url: "fs/servlet/CS"
      });
      $("#" + id + "Table").jqGrid('navGrid',"#" + id + "Pager",{edit:true,add:true,del:true});
```

Comment: What version of jqGrid are you using?  I've had some components break when I upgraded.  Try: $("#" + id + "Table").jqGrid('navGrid',"#navGrid",{edit:true,add:true,del:true});

Comment: You should use `"#" + id + "Pager"` as the value of `pager` parameter of jqGrid. You current code looks `$("#" + id + "Table").jqGrid({..., pager: '#' + id + 'Table', ...);` which is your typing error. Additionally I would recommend you to use `gridview: true, autoencode: true, height: "auto"` options and remove unneeded `scroll: false`.

Comment: Oops typo indeed. Thanks Oleg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your pager to be the same element as the grid:

It should be different

Ex
Html

```
    <div>
        <table id="gridId"  class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
        <div id="pagerId" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
    </div>
```

And then your pager would be setup via

`pager: $('#pagerId'),`